# How to use subprocess to unzip gz file in python

Tags: python, linux, debian, subprocess, gzip

I dont know how to unzip gz file in python using subprocess.

gzip library is so slow and i was thinking to make the same function above using gnu/linux shell code and subprocess library.

```
def __unzipGz(filePath):
  import gzip

  inputFile   =   gzip.GzipFile(filePath, 'rb')
  stream      =   inputFile.read()
  inputFile.close()

  outputFile  =   file(os.path.splitext(filePath)[0], 'wb')
  outputFile.write(stream)
  outputFile.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like this:

```
import subprocess

filename = "some.gunzip.file.tar.gz"
output = subprocess.Popen(['tar', '-xzf', filename])
```

Since there is no much useful output here, You could also use `os.system` instead of `subprocess.Popen` like this:

```
import os

filename = "some.gunzip.file.tar.gz"
exit_code = os.system("tar -xzf {}".format(filename))
```

Comment: Thank you! The file is a gz file so im thinking about use zcat to extract de .gz file. This function decompress not only one file so, i need to wait the command to finalice execution?

Comment: Haven't use `zcat`, so can't tell how it works. For `tar`, it will extract all files and then exit (which will block program until extraction process is finished).

Comment: Thank you, finally i solved using os.system and gunzip function